# How to filter data using custom fields in Process Shipment in acumatica?

Tags: acumatica

I am trying to filter records in the Process Shipment filter using user defined fields in SOOrder table.
I have overridden the entire Order function in Extension of SOShipmentFilter and added my condition to filter data based on SOOrder custom fields.

```
 switch (sAlias)
            {
                case "EMB": ((PXSelectBase<SOShipment>)cmd).WhereAnd<Where<SOOrderExtNV.usrIsEmbroidery, Equal<True>>>(); break;
                case "SNP": ((PXSelectBase<SOShipment>)cmd).WhereAnd<Where<SOOrderExtNV.usrIsScreenPrint, Equal<True>>>(); break;
                case "PRO": ((PXSelectBase<SOShipment>)cmd).WhereAnd<Where<SOOrderExtNV.usrIsPromo, Equal<True>>>(); break;
                case "FUL": ((PXSelectBase<SOShipment>)cmd).WhereAnd<Where<SOOrderExtNV.usrIsFulfilment, Equal<True>>>(); break;
                case "BLK": ((PXSelectBase<SOShipment>)cmd).WhereAnd<Where<SOOrderExtNV.usrIsBlank, Equal<True>>>(); break;
                case "SMP": ((PXSelectBase<SOShipment>)cmd).WhereAnd<Where<SOOrderExtNV.usrIsSample, Equal<True>>>(); break;
                case "IRN": ((PXSelectBase<SOShipment>)cmd).WhereAnd<Where<SOOrderExtNV.usrIsOronOn, Equal<True>>>(); break;
                case "DP": ((PXSelectBase<SOShipment>)cmd).WhereAnd<Where<SOOrderExtNV.usrIsDigitalPrint, Equal<True>>>(); break;
                case "BAN": ((PXSelectBase<SOShipment>)cmd).WhereAnd<Where<SOOrderExtNV.usrIsBanners, Equal<True>>>(); break;
                case "DCL": ((PXSelectBase<SOShipment>)cmd).WhereAnd<Where<SOOrderExtNV.usrIsDealer, Equal<True>>>(); break;
                case "LSR": ((PXSelectBase<SOShipment>)cmd).WhereAnd<Where<SOOrderExtNV.usrIsLaser, Equal<True>>>(); break;
                case "SVR": ((PXSelectBase<SOShipment>)cmd).WhereAnd<Where<SOOrderExtNV.usrIsService, Equal<True>>>(); break;
                default: break;
            }
```

I have debugged the code and it failes when it Iterate throught recordset

```
foreach (object res in ((PXSelectBase<SOShipment>)cmd).View.Select(null, null, PXView.Searches, PXView.SortColumns, PXView.Descendings, newFilters.ToArray(), ref startRow, PXView.MaximumRows, ref totalRows))
            {
                SOShipment order = PXResult.Unwrap<SOShipment>(res);
                SOOrder so = PXResult.Unwrap<SOOrder>(res);

                if (order.BilledOrderCntr + order.UnbilledOrderCntr + order.ReleasedOrderCntr == 1)
                {
                    order.CustomerOrderNbr = so.CustomerOrderNbr;
                }

                SOShipment cached = (SOShipment)Base.Orders.Cache.Locate(order);
                if (cached != null)
                    order.Selected = cached.Selected;
                yield return order;
            }
```

The trace having following error recorded

```
Incorrect syntax near '='.
```

I have profiled the using SQL Profiler and the  condition added is

```
(  = CONVERT(BIT, 1))
```

I have copied the SOOrderExtNV code for reference

```
    using System;
using PX.Data;
using PX.Objects.CM;
using PX.Objects.AR;
using PX.Objects.CS;
using PX.Objects.CR;
using PX.Objects.TX;

using PX.Objects.GL;
using PX.Objects.IN;
using PX.Objects.CA;
using PX.Objects.PM;
using PX.Objects.EP;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using PX.Objects;
using PX.Objects.SO;
using PX.Objects.SM;
using KevinCustomNew;

namespace KevinCustomNew
{
 [PXKeyValueStorage]
public class SOOrderExtNV: PXCacheExtension<PX.Objects.SO.SOOrder>
{
    // Sales Order Header 
    #region SO Order Header
        #region UsrOrderNature


        [PXDBString(5)]
        [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Order Nature")]
        [PXDefault("HA")]
        [PXStringList(
            new[] { "HA", "CO" },
            new[] { "House Account", "Contract order" }
         )]
        public virtual string UsrOrderNature { get; set; }
        public abstract class usrOrderNature : IBqlField { }

        #endregion
        #region UsrIsNewCustomer


        [PXDBBool]
        [PXUIField(DisplayName = "New Customer Order")]

        public virtual bool? UsrIsNewCustomer { get; set; }
        public abstract class usrIsNewCustomer : IBqlField { }

        #endregion
        #region UsrIsScreenPrint


        [PXDBBool]
        [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Screen Print")]
        [PXDefault(false)]
        public virtual bool? UsrIsScreenPrint { get; set; }
        public abstract class usrIsScreenPrint : IBqlField { }

        #endregion
        #region UsrIsEmbroidery


        [PXDBBool]
        [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Embroidery")]
        [PXDefault(false)]
        public virtual bool? UsrIsEmbroidery { get; set; }
        public abstract class usrIsEmbroidery : IBqlField { }

        #endregion
        #region UsrIsPromo


        [PXDBBool]
        [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Promotional")]
        [PXDefault(false)]
        public virtual bool? UsrIsPromo { get; set; }
        public abstract class usrIsPromo : IBqlField { }

        #endregion
        #region UsrIsBlank


        [PXDBBool]
        [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Blank")]
        [PXDefault(false)]
        public virtual bool? UsrIsBlank { get; set; }
        public abstract class usrIsBlank : IBqlField { }

        #endregion
        #region UsrIsService


        [PXDBBool]
        [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Service")]
        [PXDefault(false)]
        public virtual bool? UsrIsService { get; set; }
        public abstract class usrIsService : IBqlField { }

        #endregion
        #region UsrIsDealer


        [PXDBBool]
        [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Decal")]
        [PXDefault(false)]
        public virtual bool? UsrIsDealer { get; set; }
        public abstract class usrIsDealer : IBqlField { }

        #endregion
        #region UsrIsDigitalPrint


        [PXDBBool]
        [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Digital Print")]
        [PXDefault(false)]
        public virtual bool? UsrIsDigitalPrint { get; set; }
        public abstract class usrIsDigitalPrint : IBqlField { }

        #endregion
        #region UsrIsBanners


        [PXDBBool]
        [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Banners")]
        [PXDefault(false)]
        public virtual bool? UsrIsBanners { get; set; }
        public abstract class usrIsBanners : IBqlField { }

        #endregion
        #region UsrIsSample


        [PXDBBool]
        [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Sample")]
        [PXDefault(false)]
        public virtual bool? UsrIsSample { get; set; }
        public abstract class usrIsSample : IBqlField { }

        #endregion
        #region UsrIsFulfilment


        [PXDBBool]
        [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Fulfillment")]
        [PXDefault(false)]
        public virtual bool? UsrIsFulfilment { get; set; }
        public abstract class usrIsFulfilment : IBqlField { }

        #endregion
        #region UsrIsOronOn


        [PXDBBool]
        [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Iron On")]
        [PXDefault(false)]
        public virtual bool? UsrIsOronOn { get; set; }
        public abstract class usrIsOronOn : IBqlField { }

        #endregion
        #region UsrIsRushJob


        [PXDBBool]
        [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Rush Job")]
        [PXDefault(false)]
        public virtual bool? UsrIsRushJob { get; set; }
        public abstract class usrIsRushJob : IBqlField { }

        #endregion
        #region UsrIsLaser


        [PXDBBool]
        [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Laser")]

        public virtual bool? UsrIsLaser { get; set; }
        public abstract class usrIsLaser : IBqlField { }

        #endregion
        #region UsrIsInHandsDate


        [PXDBDate]
        [PXUIField(DisplayName = "In-Hands Date")]

        public virtual DateTime? UsrIsInHandsDate { get; set; }
        public abstract class usrIsInHandsDate : IBqlField { }

        #endregion
        #region UsrOpportunityID
        [PXDBString(20)]
        [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Opportunity",Enabled=false)]
        [PXSelector(typeof(CROpportunity.opportunityID),
                      new Type[]
                {
                 typeof(CROpportunity.opportunityID),
                 typeof(CROpportunity.opportunityName)
                },
                DescriptionField = typeof(CROpportunity.opportunityName))]
        public virtual string UsrOpportunityID { get; set; }
        public abstract class usrOpportunityID : IBqlField { }
        #endregion
        #region UsrHardDate


        [PXDBBool]
        [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Hard Date")]
        [PXDefault(false)]
        public virtual bool? UsrHardDate { get; set; }
        public abstract class usrHardDate : IBqlField { }

        #endregion
        #region UsrEventDate


        [PXDBDate]
        [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Event Date")]

        public virtual DateTime? UsrEventDate { get; set; }
        public abstract class usrEventDate : IBqlField { }

        #endregion
        #region UsrEventDescription


        [PXDBString(512)]
        [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Event Description")]

        public virtual string UsrEventDescription { get; set; }
        public abstract class usrEventDescription : IBqlField { }

        #endregion
        #region UsrSoHeaderNoOfPieces


        [PXDBInt]
        [PXUIField(DisplayName = "No. Of Pieces")]

        public virtual int? UsrSoHeaderNoOfPieces { get; set; }
        public abstract class usrSoHeaderNoOfPieces : IBqlField { }

        #endregion
        #region UsrShipDate
        [PXDBDate]
        [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Ship Date")]

        public virtual DateTime? UsrShipDate { get; set; }
        public abstract class usrShipDate : IBqlField { }

        #endregion
        #region UsrHoldUntil
        [PXDBDate]
        [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Hold Until")]

        public virtual DateTime? UsrHoldUntil { get; set; }
        public abstract class usrHoldUntil : IBqlField { }

        #endregion
        #region UsrCustomerContact
        [PXDBInt]
        [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Contact")]
        [PXSelector(
                    typeof(Search<Contact.contactID,
                    Where<Contact.bAccountID, Equal<Current<SOOrder.customerID>>,And<Contact.contactType,Equal<DownLoadValueType.CustomerContactType>>>>),
                    DescriptionField = typeof(Contact.displayName))]
        public virtual int? UsrCustomerContact { get; set; }
        public abstract class usrCustomerContact : IBqlField { }

        #endregion
        #region UsrBatchShip
        [PXDBBool]
        [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Batch Ship")]

        public virtual bool? UsrBatchShip { get; set; }
        public abstract class usrBatchShip : IBqlField { }

        #endregion
        #region UsrReadyForProduction
        [PXDBBool]
        [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Ready for Production")]

        public virtual bool? UsrReadyForProduction { get; set; }
        public abstract class usrReadyForProduction : IBqlField { }

        #endregion
        #region UsrEditInstructions
        [PXDBString(2000)]
        [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Revision Instructions")]

        public virtual string UsrEditInstructions { get; set; }
        public abstract class usrEditInstructions : IBqlField { }

        #endregion
    #endregion

    }

}
```

Regards,
R.Muralidharan

Comment: Can you provide the complete declaration of SOOrderExtNV? Seems like BQL is unable to resolve it.

Comment: I have copied the SOOrderExtNV Extension code for reference

Comment: I notice that you're using key-value storage for your fields (PXKeyValueStorage attribute). Can you try with standard storage to see if it works? I confirmed with engineering that this scenario should work with key-value storage, but i'm suspecting it has something to do with the problem.

Comment: The user defined fields are used extensive in my customization. I am creating a sample project and test the concept

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of re-declaring entire base code of view delegate in Extension, you should execute the same data view through the base class by using Base.Orders.Select() in extension class and apply your custom filters.

Below code snippet shows you concept to achieve what you are looking for (and feel free to adjust as per your need):

Create DAC Extension for SOShipmentFilter DAC

```cs
public class SOShipmentFilterPXExt : PXCacheExtension<SOShipmentFilter>
{
    #region UsrFilterByAlias

    public abstract class usrFilterByAlias : IBqlField { }

    [PXDBString(2)]
    [PXStringList(
              new[] {"A0", "A1", "A2" },
              new[] {"All", "UsrZField1", "UsrZField2" }
                 )]
    [PXDefault("A0")]
    public virtual String UsrFilterByAlias { get; set; }

    #endregion
}
```

Create DAC Extension for SOOrder DAC

```cs
[PXKeyValueStorage]
public class SOOrderExtNV : PXCacheExtension<PX.Objects.SO.SOOrder>
{
    #region UsrZField1

    public abstract class usrZField1 : IBqlField { }

    [PXDBBool]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "ZField1")]
    public virtual bool? UsrZField1 { get; set; }

    #endregion

    #region UsrZField2

    public abstract class usrZField2 : IBqlField { }

    [PXDBBool]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "ZField2")]
    public virtual bool? UsrZField2 { get; set; }

    #endregion
}
```

Create DAC Extension for SOShipment DAC

```cs
public class SOShipmentExt : PXCacheExtension<SOShipment>
{
    #region UsrZField1

    public abstract class usrZField1 : IBqlField { }

    [PXBool]
    [PXDefault(false, PersistingCheck = PXPersistingCheck.Nothing)]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "ZField1")]

    public virtual bool? UsrZField1 { get; set; }
    #endregion

    #region UsrZField2

    public abstract class usrZField2 : IBqlField { }

    [PXBool]
    [PXDefault(false, PersistingCheck = PXPersistingCheck.Nothing)]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "ZField2")]

    public virtual bool? UsrZField2 { get; set; }

    #endregion
}
```

Create Graph Extension

```cs
public class SOInvoiceShipmentPXExt : PXGraphExtension<SOInvoiceShipment>
{
    [PXFilterable]
    public PXFilteredProcessing<SOShipment, SOShipmentFilter> Orders;

    public virtual void SOShipment_RowSelecting(PXCache sender, PXRowSelectingEventArgs e, PXRowSelecting BaseInvoke)
    {
        if (BaseInvoke != null)
            BaseInvoke(sender, e);

        if (e.Row == null) return;

        SOShipment shipment = (SOShipment)e.Row;
        SOShipmentExt shipmentExt = PXCache<SOShipment>.GetExtension<SOShipmentExt>(shipment);
        SOOrder soData = PXSelectJoin<SOOrder,
                                        InnerJoin<SOOrderShipment, On<SOOrderShipment.orderType, Equal<SOOrder.orderType>,
                                                                    And<SOOrderShipment.orderNbr, Equal<SOOrder.orderNbr>>>>,
                                        Where<SOOrderShipment.shipmentType, Equal<Required<SOOrderShipment.shipmentType>>,
                                            And<SOOrderShipment.shipmentNbr, Equal<Required<SOOrderShipment.shipmentNbr>>>>>
                                        .Select(Base, shipment.ShipmentType, shipment.ShipmentNbr);
        if (soData != null)
        {
            SOOrderExtNV soDataExt = PXCache<SOOrder>.GetExtension<SOOrderExtNV>(soData);
            shipmentExt.UsrZField1 = soDataExt.UsrZField1;
            shipmentExt.UsrZField2 = soDataExt.UsrZField2;
        }
    }

    protected IEnumerable orders()
    {
        SOShipmentFilterPXExt filterExt = PXCache<SOShipmentFilter>.GetExtension<SOShipmentFilterPXExt>(Base.Filter.Current);
        if (filterExt.UsrFilterByAlias == "A1")
        {
            var list = new ArrayList();
            foreach (PXResult record in Base.Orders.Select())
            {
                SOShipment shipment = record.GetItem<SOShipment>();
                if (shipment != null)
                {
                    SOShipmentExt shipmentExt = PXCache<SOShipment>.GetExtension<SOShipmentExt>(shipment);
                    if (shipmentExt.UsrZField1.HasValue && shipmentExt.UsrZField1.Value)
                        list.Add(shipment);
                }
            }
            return list;
        }
        else if (filterExt.UsrFilterByAlias == "A2")
        {
            var list = new ArrayList();
            foreach (PXResult record in Base.Orders.Select())
            {
                SOShipment shipment = record.GetItem<SOShipment>();
                if (shipment != null)
                {
                    SOShipmentExt shipmentExt = PXCache<SOShipment>.GetExtension<SOShipmentExt>(shipment);
                    if (shipmentExt.UsrZField2.HasValue && shipmentExt.UsrZField2.Value)
                        list.Add(shipment);
                }
            }
            return list;
        }
        else
        {
            return Base.Orders.Select();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have tested the concept and it is working fine. I will mark it accepted after testing few more entries
Thanks